# How do I include global styles/javascript in HTML files displayed as dialogs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, include

I am developing a Google App Script project that will be used right from within a Google Sheet, with HTML files as dialogs. My project will be a mix of .gs files as well as HTML files for data entry, etc. I am trying to use the methodology explained here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript

to create global JavaScript and CSS modules that I can include in my HTML files rather than cutting and pasting inline code all over the place. This will be mainly useful for the data-saving routines which capture form data, serialize it, then save it to Sheets via the methodology outlined here (and many other places): http://railsrescue.com/blog/2015-05-28-step-by-step-setup-to-send-form-data-to-google-sheets/.

The problem I am having is with trying to call the "include" statement from my HTML files, namely, lines like:

```
<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
```

It doesn't work when I create a menu on the spreadsheet to display my HTML file as a dialog -- the text of the include line just shows up as literal output on the dialog, and code does not appear to be getting included (not in scope).

I know the Google example is primarily for pages delpoyed via a web app, but I'd like to use my HTML files as dialogs right inside the spreadsheet (e.g. from a menu or sidebar) -- that feels nice and tidy to me. But if I can't get includes to work, my code base is going to be a nightmare and it will be really, really hard to standardize CSS across the whole app. I don't want to be cutting and pasting all the time.

So, what is the secret behind this `<?!` tag, and why won't it work in my HTML files when they are called as dialogs? It is clear those lines are different from the get-go (maybe not in a bad way, but they don't work), as the Google Scripting console displays those lines oddly, as depicted in the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
```

More information can be found in [Adding Style Sheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Tutorial/Adding_Style_Sheets).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how that is going to help. If I try adding that line to the HTML file I am attempting to display as a dialog, it still has that different formatting in the code window, and nothing changes. It seems to me that the `<?` tag just doesn't operate correctly in HTML files displayed as dialogs with `showModalDialog()`.

Comment: Now that I have figured out how to get the dialog dynamically built the `<?>` works. So, your comment is applicable as I dive further into adding style sheets properly to my project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was not properly understanding the way the HTML was being served up as a dialog. I was using this behind a custom menu option:

```
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(htmlFileName);
```

when I should have been using the more dynamic:

```
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(htmlFileName).evaluate();
```

The latter generates a user interface object where the server-side script is executed and everything is included properly when I display the object with `showModalDialog()` (or `showSidebar()`).

I just had a complete misunderstanding of how the user interface object was being created, so now all scripting works inside my HTML files.